# Find all network interface(net_device) in linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm trying to develop a sys call for all network interfaces in system.
Which structure has all of network interfaces?
How does Linux Kernel find network interfaces and how populates it?
It seems a linked list of net_device structure.

Comment: The net modules are in `/lib/modules/[uname -r]/kernel/drivers/net/` and `/lib/modules/[uname -r]/kernel/net/`

Comment: @KnudLarsen As per my understating he is looking for the structures used to develop the sys call for network interface not for the module installation path on the target.

Comment: `net_device_ops` structure handle the network system call. Already here are a lot of system call examples on google which you can take for the reference.